# upgrading angular 1.x directive to angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to upgrade some directives to angular 2 but I am not able to find how each attributes translates to angular 2. Suppose I want to upgrade following, how can it be done? Please let me know, or guide me to a place where I can find it. Thx

```
 angular.module('grid.provider', [])
    .provider('gridFactory', function() {
      'use strict';
       this.defaults = {};
      this.factory = function (options) {
        return new Grid(options); //from included js
      };

    angular.module('grid.init', ['grid.provider'])
      .controller('gridCtrl', ['$scope', '$attrs', 'gridFactory',
      function ($scope, $attrs, gridFactory) {
       var options = angular.extend({}, $scope.$eval($attrs.gridInit));
        var grid= gridFactory.create(options);

        grid.on('getAll', function (gridEventName) {
          var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
          args.shift();
          var event = $scope.$broadcast.apply($scope, ['grid::' + gridEventName, grid].concat(args));
          if ({
            'success':1, 'error':1
          }[gridEventName]) {
            $scope.$apply();
          }

        });


      }])
      .directive('gridInit', [function() {
        return {
          scope: true,
          controller: 'gridCtrl'
        };
      }]);


    angular.module('grid.saveBtn', ['grid.init'])
    .directive('saveBtn', [function() {
      return {
        'restrict': 'E',
        'scope': false,
        'require': '^gridInit',
         'link': function(scope, element, attrs) {
                //script to save
        }

      };
    }]);
```

Comment: Your question should show what you have tried and where you failed. SO in not a bunch of code monkeys who translate code from one framework to another. Check out http://angular.io first and if you can't figure something out on your own, then add a question.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Actually I am stuck with scope and upgrade factory to angular 2 equivalent and injecting it to directive. I am trying to find these in angular.io. I asked this question here just to find out if someone has already gone through this and can help sparing few mins. No need to translate if someone has to spend a lot of time like what I am doing now.

Comment: In Angular2 you use shared services instead of scope. I don't know what "upgrade factory" is (don't know Angular1 well).

Comment: thx for the comment. I found it overwhelming and not able to find upgrade guide for what I am trying to upgrade, there is provider, injection from different angular modules, $scope.broadcast, event bubbling and more. I may need to wait for this upgrade.